# Default row selection for dataTable primeNG

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, primeng-datatable

How could I select automatically a row in dataTable after a given record? The dataTable has sorted column, and pagination. After a given record I would expect the record to be selected on the page that exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dataTable has a property(an array) called `[(selection)]`, to add/remove/preselect rows you can just add/remove values from your array

to pre-select the `nth`:

**component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.data = [/*data*/];           
   this.selectedItems = [ this.data[n-1]];
 }
```

**template:**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [(selection)]="selectedItems">
```

[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/HCBUuk/)

Comment: Thank you. My selection should be just a value from the array. I added, but the row still doesn't get selected( or highlighted). Maybe am I doing something wrong?...

Comment: Thank you for the example. Let me try it again and come back with response. Thank you Kld.

Comment: @Kld, what if i have a checkbox/radio button for the selected rows. It doesn't get  selected, even though i have my selected items in this.selectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

The following will help.

In the HTML part add this attribute to the datatable

```
 [(selectedRow)] = "rowIWantToGetSelected"
```

In the component just populate this "rowIWantToGetSelected" with the item from the array. e.g. This is for first row

```
this.rowIWantToGetSelected = recordsArray[0]
```

**IMPORTANT**:  Ng prime expects a property named rowId with the row number (starting index 0).  If your model doesn't have it, Add that property to it and update it with the row number. If you don't have this property, it won't select the expected row. Following is the example of selecting the first row.

```
this.rowIWantToGetSelected = { 
  ...recordsArray[0],
  rowId : 0
}
```